# Meteor - featured image from URL

Tags: javascript, url, meteor

We have a field in our app for a URL to be pasted as part of a record. I'd like the option for a featured image to be grabbed from that URL, like sharing a link on facebook. It would be great if the user could cycle through the images to get the most appropriate one!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used cheerio on the server to manipulate the page I get using HTTP. After it's just cycling thru the images and building your array. Look into gotlogin.com code (github link in footer)